# CSS - Div background color becomes transparent, IE8 --

Tags: css, background, doctype

I'm now building a website for my sister. It looks normal on Chrome, firefox and IE9 but for some reasons, some of my div lost all background color in IE 7 --.

http://xx3004.kodingen.com/JDProperties

Open the website and you can see the pop up message has problem with title and button set (background color) - I'm using IE 7 right now. Then the content of the left body lost background color too, and the right column lost background too. I've been doing many searches on Google plus I notice that jQueryUI could not be wrong, so I guess it's because of my DOCTYPE in the begining of the source code. I've tried to change to some other DOCTYPE I saw on the Internet, or even omit it, but the website becomes either messing up or remains the same.

This is the first time I see this situation, it's weird and I hope I don't know how to fix it.

I'm expecting to solve the problems soon :-). Thanks everyone in advanced.

[x]

Comment: You have a special reason to use the modal form? That tends to confuse, since you can not access the rest of the elements of the web without closing the dialog. Is more recommended for forms and notifications.

Comment: I can only get access on the internet 4 or 5 days a week, so I am trying my best to tell you if your answer can solve my problem. Once again I'm sorry for letting you guys wait. [x]

Answer (score 1):

I started to look, and then saw this

```
</head> 
  <body> 

 </body> 

 </html>    

</head>

<body>..
```

Try building the structure properly and see what happens yo.

Comment: Hi, it happens because actually I write 3 different pages: header.php, index.php and footer.php, then I use include() to embed them, this way once I want to edit the navigation bar or footer, it would become eaiser. That will probably be the problem, let me try to remove them then I will tell if it works as soon as I can get on the internet. Your answer probably is what I need. +1. [x]

Answer (score 1):

You have mismatched HTML tags.   Chrome, firefox and IE9 are cleaning up for you, but IE7 isn't that nice.

Comment: IE7 isn't that good, rather, although this issue should really just be reported instead of being fixed. The W3C validator helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try to remove as many unnecessary tags as possible, I'm just wondering will it still work when I make a header.php, footer.php to embed into index.php (using `include()`) without those tags (`<html><body>....`);

Comment: I did and it didn't work as expected. Please take a look at it: http://xx3004.kodingen.com/JDProperties [x]

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @albert, you do need to recode that page, although it's seeming to mostly working, the nesting of multiple `head, body, style` elements going to lead to trouble, and I suggest you change to an HTML4 Doctype as the coding is not XHTML, the more conflicts (tag soup) a browser has to deal with the more likely you will get them interpreting your intentions differently.

As for the IE backgrounds in numerous (inline styles) places you have `background: inherit` IE does not understand the "inherit" value of properties  - or more specifically for IE7 and earlier it only applied "inherit to the `direction` and `visibility` properties

Comment: Hi I've edited it, you can now please check it again, it still didn't work: http://xx3004.kodingen.com/JDProperties I've removed unnecessary tags (such as `<html><body><head>...` and change the DOCTYPE to HTML4 but it stays the same. Do you have any idea of what to do? [x]